# Copy the Row Where in ColB Each cell is Greater than 0

Tags: excel, vba

I have created this below code which copies on condition that if Col"B" any cell is greater than 0 then copy the complete row (I want here to copy the Row from A to G instead of complete Row).

and paste that row in another sheet but my code just paste the last row instead of multiple rows which are greater than 0.

your help will be apprecaited.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheet3
Set ws2 = Sheet5

lr = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ws1.Range("B3:B" & lr)

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value > 0 Then
        cell.EntireRow.Copy
            ws2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: It is copying all the rows.  You are just pasting over them and only see the last occurrence.  You need to increment the paste row.

Comment: Can you please post an answer how to increment for pasting,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheet3
Set ws2 = Sheet5
Dim n as Long

lr = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ws1.Range("B3:B" & lr)
n=1
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value > 0 Then
        ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(cell.Row, "A"), ws1.Cells(cell.Row, "G")).Copy
        ws2.Range("A"& n).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        n=n+1
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: I want here to copy the Row from A to G instead of complete Row. How to do this @Darrell H